# How do I convert answer assigned as a string back to long variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable I need as a number which I use to find the last row in groups of rows on my worksheet. It is set as long at the start of my code however when this variable is amended by finding the next row address using:

```
end = Mid(searchTerm.Address(0, 0), 2)
```

the row number assigned is then a string, such as `end = "72"`. What is the simplest way to convert this back to a long variable so then `end=72` (the answer can be over 500000 hence not using integer) as I then use this with a `Do Until x>end` loop? Thanks

Comment: What about **[CLng()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/type-conversion-functions)**?

Comment: CLng()  - All the functions starting with C convert between datatypes

Comment: Don't go via  string at all. Option 1) `Dim yourvariable As Long` Option 2) `yourvariable = searchTerm.Row`

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: seems to me you just want. `end = searchterm.row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`end = CLng(Mid(searchTerm.Address(0, 0), 2))`